# IdHttp : Error 10053 when sending login post

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy, indy10, idhttp

No matter what i do or try, I keep getting 10053 error when sending login post for a site
I use the code below to send the login post parameters which you also can see, it has a `VerificationCode` which i must extract from the login page first and i do and replace with the previous value
**After sending the post** I get an 10053 error (`software caused connection abort`) and http analyzer shows `<Request is not completed.  waiting...>`

My code :

```
mIdHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
mIdHttp.AllowCookies := true;
mIdHttp.HandleRedirects := true;
mIdHttp.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
mIdHttp.ConnectTimeout := 2000000;

// Headers, all values are what Http Analyzer shows 
mIdHttp.Request.Host := 'apps.somesite.com';
mIdHttp.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
mIdHttp.Request.CacheControl := 'max-age=0';
mIdHttp.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36 OPR/39.0.2256.48';
mIdHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
mIdHttp.Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
mIdHttp.Request.Referer := 'https://apps.somesite.com/Login';
mIdHttp.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate, lzma, br';
mIdHttp.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'en-US,en;q=0.8';
mIdHttp.Request.ContentLength := 195;  

// Extracting __RequestVerificationToken from login page
rvt := getRequestVerificationToken();

// prepare request
request.add('__RequestVerificationToken=' + rvt);
request.add('UserName=someUsername');
request.add('Password=somePassword');
request.add('RememberMe=false');

// sending login post
URL := 'https://apps.somesite.com/Login';
// Error Happens At The Post Below
mIdHttp.post(URL, request, responseCode);
```

Here is the Http analyzer `post paramters` :

```
Parameter Name              Value                                                                                                         
__RequestVerificationToken  h_9onTJNqodkc0hVa5_VVAAa0izMb9zDdVeO5hDkciunk-3I2u7PpS8OPQe-puloMo7GRtI4iwMwezU3Nv70Wk2olccJK7MbuhgPWAGGFbM1  
UserName                    someUsername                                                                                                       
Password                    somePassword                                                                                              
RememberMe                  false
```

Except the site address (which i can not share for privacy reasons) please tell if you need any more info or need me to check anything, i have been trying changing all kind of idHttp parameters that i could think of for the past 3 days and i always get the same error

**Note**, One thing i should mention is that if Http Analyzer program is on, and i start my program, instead of 10053 i get 10054 ~! but without any thing interfering i always get 10053.

**Edit 1 :**
a screenshot of the **header** of the post that is sent when i **login using a browser**

[image]

a screenshot of the **header** of the post that is sent when i **try to login using idHttp.post()**
[image]

Comment: Why do you set ContentType, ContentLength and AcceptEncoding? These fields are automatically generated. Have you tried to add a small delay between your requests?

Comment: @smooty86 i was simply being through, and i tried from sleep(500) to sleep(2000), same error happens.

Comment: @smooty86: Indy does not support `lzma` or `br` encodings, but the app might, so it is fine to set the `AcceptEncoding` for those if the app is prepared to handle them. But definitely *DO NOT* manually set `gzip` or `deflate`. Those are handled by `TIdHTTP` if it has a `Compressor` component assigned to it.

Comment: @AliAhmadi: those socket errors mean the connection is being closed abnormally. If it is happening during an HTTP post, the most likely culprit is the HTTP server itself does not like your post data and is kicking you out instead of sending an HTTP error. It is really hard to diagnose your problem without a simpler example (that doesn't involve your utility classes), or at least a capture of the HTTP traffic from a packet sniffer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i changed the example to a simpler one, if possible, i will try to put a screenshot of a `packet sniffer` as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can tell me what is it that you are looking for in packet sniffer ?, i can look for it and tell you the results.

Comment: @AliAhmadi: I see nothing in those headers that would cause your problem. You didn't show the post data, though. But the `Content-Length` is the same between the two sets, so I *assume* the post data is exactly identical, is that right? You will likely have to contact the server admin for further help.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes exactly, both post datas are identical, and it is kinda super hard to get in contact with the server admin, is there any other way ?, can you understand the problem using `packet sniffer` screen shot ?

Comment: @AliAhmadi: there is nothing in the code or the HTTP traffic to indicate why this is failing. So this is likely a networking issue, not a coding issue. You need to contact the server admin and have them watch the activity while you run your tests, to see if they notice anything happening on their end.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for your help, just one last question, doesn't idHttp do what a browser does ?, if its not a coding issue why the browsers do not have the same problem ? whats the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

try to add in your code this:

```
include(idhttp1.HTTPOptions,[hoKeepOrigProtocol]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are behind a proxy. When behind a proxy, IdHTTP has to first connect to the proxy. It disconnects and throws a EIdConnClosedGracefully error. Then you are connected and can post your request.

Please try this :

```
mIdHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := ProxyServerURL;
mIdHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 80;
// if your proxy requires authentication, provide the login and password, else set BasicAuthentication to false.
mIdHttp.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := true; 
mIdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyUserName := proxylogin;
mIdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPassword := proxypwd;
try
  TATDIdHttpUtility.post(mIdHttp, URL, request).rawResponseCode.SaveToFile('responseCode0.txt');
except
  on E: EIdConnClosedGracefully do
  begin
    TATDIdHttpUtility.post(mIdHttp, URL, request).rawResponseCode.SaveToFile('responseCode0.txt');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not using any proxy, and the error is `software caused connection abort`

Comment: @chadkops: What you describe is completely wrong. If the target server requires a proxy to reach it, and if `TIdHTTP` is disconnected from the proxy, it would not be able to reach the target server at all. If `Post()` gets disconnected, calling `Post()` again would reconnect to the proxy before sending the new request. The request is sent **through** the proxy, so the connection to the proxy has to stay up. You can't be disconnected from the proxy but still remain connected to the target server.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right thanks. Guess I've been doing it wrong, but it didn't work in my case with a IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and proxy auth. Trying differently this morning thanks to you and I don't have the ClosedGracefully exception anymore.